# TypeError: _setup_transcribe_dataloader() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'

Tags: torch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to use "_setup_transcribe_dataloader" function which calling "_setup_dataloader_from_config" function , but when calling it in the main function ,I get "_setup_transcribe_dataloader() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'

```
def _setup_transcribe_dataloader(self, config: dict) -> 'torch.utils.data.DataLoader':
        """
        Setup function for a temporary data loader which wraps the provided audio file.

        Args:
            config: A python dictionary which contains the following keys:
            paths2audio_files: (a list) of paths to audio files. The files should be relatively short fragments. \
                Recommended length per file is between 5 and 25 seconds.
            batch_size: (int) batch size to use during inference. \
                Bigger will result in better throughput performance but would use more memory.
            temp_dir: (str) A temporary directory where the audio manifest is temporarily
                stored.

        Returns:
            A pytorch DataLoader for the given audio file(s).
        """
        if 'manifest_filepath' in config:
            manifest_filepath = config['manifest_filepath']
            batch_size = config['batch_size']
        else:
            manifest_filepath = os.path.join(config['temp_dir'], 'manifest.json')
            batch_size = min(config['batch_size'], len(config['paths2audio_files']))
        dl_config = {
            'manifest_filepath': manifest_filepath,
            'sample_rate': self.preprocessor._sample_rate,
            'labels': self.joint.vocabulary,
            'batch_size': batch_size,
            'trim_silence': False,
            'shuffle': False,
            'num_workers': config.get('num_workers', min(batch_size, os.cpu_count() - 1)),
            'pin_memory': True,
        }    
        if config.get("augmentor"):
            dl_config['augmentor'] = config.get("augmentor")

        temporary_datalayer = self._setup_dataloader_from_config(config=DictConfig(dl_config))
        return temporary_datalayer
```

```
def _setup_dataloader_from_config(self, config):
        # Automatically inject args from model config to dataloader config
        audio_to_text_dataset.inject_dataloader_value_from_model_config(self.cfg, config, key='sample_rate')
        audio_to_text_dataset.inject_dataloader_value_from_model_config(self.cfg, config, key='labels')
        dataset = audio_to_text_dataset.get_audio_to_text_char_dataset_from_config(
            config=config,
            local_rank=self.local_rank,
            global_rank=self.global_rank,
            world_size=self.world_size,
            preprocessor_cfg=self._cfg.get("preprocessor", None),
        )

        if dataset is None:
            return None

        if isinstance(dataset, AudioToCharDALIDataset):
            # DALI Dataset implements dataloader interface
            return dataset

        shuffle = config['shuffle']
        if isinstance(dataset, torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
            shuffle = False

        if hasattr(dataset, 'collate_fn'):
            collate_fn = dataset.collate_fn
        elif hasattr(dataset.datasets[0], 'collate_fn'):
            # support datasets that are lists of entries
            collate_fn = dataset.datasets[0].collate_fn
        else:
            # support datasets that are lists of lists
            collate_fn = dataset.datasets[0].datasets[0].collate_fn

        return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            dataset=dataset,
            batch_size=config['batch_size'],
            collate_fn=collate_fn,
            drop_last=config.get('drop_last', False),
            shuffle=shuffle,
            num_workers=config.get('num_workers', 0),
            pin_memory=config.get('pin_memory', False),
        )
`
```

main ():
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpgdir:
with open(os.path.join(tmpgdir, 'manifest.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
entry = {'audio_filepath': audio_filepath, 'duration': 100000, 'text': 'nothing'}
fp.write(json.dumps(entry) + '\n')

```
        config = {'paths2audio_files': [audio_filepath], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': tmpgdir}
        
        output = _setup_transcribe_dataloader(config)
```

```
`
```

I want to use "_setup_transcribe_dataloader" function which calling "_setup_dataloader_from_config" function , but when calling it in the main function ,I get "_setup_transcribe_dataloader() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'. I tried to print the config and get output

```
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0001.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmp_yczkg8h'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0002.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmp5ragvxv5'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0003.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmpews5t2rv'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0004.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmpvqw9pg9m'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0005.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmp72gunxr_'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0006.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmpnp2u80en'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0007.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmpcwfg0q8b'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0008.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmp7hhfkwx6'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0009.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmppokj7tig'}
{'paths2audio_files': ['rasptest/61-70968-0010.wav'], 'batch_size': 1, 'temp_dir': '/tmp/tmpjx3gpc_n'}
```